# angularjs and grails 2.5.0 save success, no errors but not saving to database

Tags: angularjs, database, grails, h2, angular-resource

I've been looking for similar situations like mine has and I've seen that it is common to have this error but I can not find the right solution with my problem. I would really appreciate any help.

My problem right now is that when I execute this it return and HTTP 200 and also prints a line on my terminal which confirms me that it creates the JSON file. There are no errors but when I checked on my database, there's nothing in it.

What I've tried so far:

1. newBook.save(flush: true)
2. edit my datasource from create-drop to update (but my whole database disappears so I returned the data. I only need to save it during a demo so I understand that the data will be lost every time the application restarts)
3. Postman GET and POST

GET: 200 OK

POST: 200 OK

but when I GET again, nothing is showing

4. debugging using console and println (but there might be something that I missed since I'm just starting to learn both AngularJS and Grails)

I am hoping that these data can give a detailed information about my problem, I am open for any questions.

Here are my sample codes:

back-end codes: Grails 2.5.0

**Domain class**

```
class Book {

    String name
    int page
    boolean new

    static belongsTo = [student: student]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
import grails.converters.JSON
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured

@Secured('permitAll')

class BookController {

    def index() {
        render Book.list() as JSON
    }

    def save() {
        def newBook = new Book(request.JSON)
        newBook.save(flush: true)
        println request.JSON
        render(['success': true] as JSON)
    }

    def show() {
        def Book = Book.get(params.id)

        render Book as JSON
    }
}
```

front-end codes: AngularJS

**Controller**
    app.controller('Book', function($scope, store, $state, bookFactory){

```
    $scope.book = {}
    $scope.saveBook = function() {
        $scope.book.assessment = $scope.getBook();
        console.log($scope.book);
        bookFactory.save($scope.book,function (result){
            console.log(result)
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }

    $scope.getBook = function() {
    var result = "";
    if ($scope.book.page > 10){
        result = "many pages";
    }else if ($scope.book.new && $scope.book.page > 20){
        result = "new and many pages";
    }else {
        result = "old book";
    }
    return result;
};  
})
```

**Service**

```
app.factory('bookFactory', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('api/book',
        {
            'update': {method: 'PUT'}
        })
}])
```

**app.js**

```
.state("book", {
        url: "/book",
        templateUrl: "assets/app/partials/book.html",
        controller: 'Book',
        data: {
            requiresLogin: true
        }
    })
```

**HTML**

```
 Book Name:
<input type="text" ng-model="book.name" name="bookName" required="" class="form-control" /> 

Number of Pages: 
<input type="number" ng-model="book.page" name="numberPage" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of Pages"/> 

Bought within the last 30 days?
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="new" value=true ng-model="book.new" >
           <font color=green>YES</font>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="new" value=false ng-model="book.new">
            <font color=red>NO</font>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<a ui-sref="book" class="btn btn-primary" name="bookBtn" ng-click="saveBook()"> Next </a>
```

Comment: Have you tried saving with `failOnError: true`? It will throw an exception when an invalid object is saved.

Comment: @tylerwal thank you for suggesting that. I managed to read and solve the problem by doing it. Since there is a **relationship* between the **student and book classes**, and I didn't use any constraints for it to be null. Grails was telling me that I have to **put a value** for the student class before it saves in the db.